# Absolutely Continuous and Radon Nikodym Derivative

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to show that the measure $\mu_1(E)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\cdot\mu_2(E\cap E_i)$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu_2$ and then compute its Radon-Nikodym derivative. Here $E_i$ are measurable sets and $c_i$ are real numbers and both $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are defined on a finite measurable space. At first, i thought that $\mu_1$ is the integral of a simple function but again i realised that $E_i$ are not necessary disjoint and so i am stuck on what to do. I will appreciate your proof.

Comment: Your first thought seems good. Why is it a problem that $E_i$ are not necessarily disjoint?

Comment: @Brent, is it okay to approach the problem this way. To find the Radon–Nikodým derivative, just compute (writing $[E]$ for the characteristic function of $E$ and using $[E \cap F] = [E] \cdot [F]$) that for all $\mu_2$-measurable

$$\mu_1(E) = \sum_{i = 1}^n c_i \mu_2(E \cap E_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \int [E] \cdot [E_i]\,d\mu_2 = \int [E] \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i [E_i]\right)\,d\mu_2$$

and observe that $f = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i [E_i]$ thus satisfies the defining property of the Radon–Nikodým derivative

Comment: Yes, that's perfect.